# SQL: split values by columns depending on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have table data after doing all joins and restrictions like this:

| Name | Type | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | mobile | /mobile/image1.jpg |
| Item 1 | desktop | /desktop/image1.jpg |
| Item 2 | mobile | /mobile/image2.jpg |
| Item 2 | desktop | /desktop/image2.jpg |

I want the result table to look like this in the end:

| Name | Path mobile | Path desktop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | /mobile/image1.jpg | /desktop/image1.jpg |
| Item 2 | /mobile/image2.jpg | /desktop/image2.jpg |

What SQL (mySQL) feature can be used to get such a result?

So far, I've had to do data processing (mapping) in the code that calls this request.

Answer (score 2):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'mobile'  THEN Path END) AS Path_Mobile,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'desktop' THEN Path END) AS Path_Desktop
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(MT.[Name]),
        MT2.[Path] AS DesktopPath,
        MT3.[Path] AS MobilePath
FROM    MyTable MT
INNER JOIN MyTable MT2
        ON MT2.[Name] = MT.[Name] AND MT2.[Type] = 'DESKTOP'
INNER JOIN MyTable MT3
        ON MT3.[Name] = MT.[Name] AND MT3.[Type] = 'MOBILE'
```